# Cookies are not being set in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cookies, next.js

I deployed an express server to heroku as well as a next.js app.
The cookies are being sent from the server and even being shown in the network tab:
[image: network tab]

However, the cookies are not actually stored, all my requests failed because they depends on the csrf cookie, and the storage tab is empty:

[image: storage tab]

This is the code for setting the cookies in the backend:

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
  },
});

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: clientOrigin }));

app.get('/', csrfProtection, function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(), { sameSite: 'none', secure: true });
  res.end();
});

app.use(csrfProtection);
```

this is my axios instance:

```
const baseURL = process.env.baseURL;

const axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

and the request code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadingAction.setToTrue());
    const getCsrf = async () => {
      await axiosInstance.get('/');
    };
    getCsrf()
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(loadingAction.setToFalse());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(loadingAction.setToFalse());
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

While looking at your screenshot - I observed that the browser has a different domain set *hilife01* vs *hilife-1*

[image]

Accessing throuugh https://hlife01.herokuapp.com/auth/login - gets you the cookies but your App doesn't have the right route configured.

Most likely, The Right domain is not associated with the cookie being set so while setting the cookie, the browser silently rejects the cookie because you are not matching the domain, however it is visible in the address bar.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on which domain you prefer, if _hilife01.herokuap..._ is good, then fix the nodejs routing for that app - if you want it to stay _hilife-1.herokuapp.com_ then find the code setting the cookie domain incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it, yet I still not completely understand. hilife01.herokuap is good. What do you mean in nodejs routing?

Comment: Yes - when you access the url you get _ Cannot GET /auth/login_

Comment: Can you please explain me in more detail what exactly my next steps should be?

Comment: In order to help you further, please post your entire code somewhere - If you  go to the URL - https://hlife01.herokuapp.com/auth/login you can see it takes you to a page that shows an error - If you checkin the entire code without sensitive data and what you tried, we can assist you.

Comment: The route in hlife01.herokuapp.com/auth/login should be a POST request, that why the error is shown. I can give you a link to my github, will it help?

Comment: Sure, however I would also ask you to locate where the cookie is being set if domain is specified

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your question. But here is the link https://github.com/AviramBaranes/Hlife

Comment: It looks like you or another contributor made the change to have the domain set to parent - https://github.com/AviramBaranes/Hlife/commit/09bf163a260c08f41756ec7280cee12bcac6fc65